# I want announcements to only show what has been posted within the past week

Tags: 2013, list-view

I have added the announcements web part to my main page and I want to filter it so that users only see announcements through the web part if the announcement has been posted within the past week.

I opened up the list view options and I see filter options. But I don't know how they work with dates because they ask for a value and then specify that it won't show if the value is less than, greater than, equal to, etc. some number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the filter at editing current view under List View Edit Properties. See the below screen shot how to apply a filter on dates.

The Date filter would be like this `[Today]-7`

[image]

Comment: I tried this and got the error
`Filter value is not in a supported date format`

Comment: There should not have any spaces between. Use like this `[Today]-7`